# SqlCommand cannot create table

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a problem with creating a table with SqlCommand. The code is as follow

```
        string cs = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="+ Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + @"\Database\Test.mdf;Integrated Security=True; Database=Test";
        SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection(cs);
        sc.Open();
        //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        try
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
            "CREATE TABLE Dogs1 (Weight INT, Name TEXT, Breed TEXT)", sc))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(command.ExecuteNonQuery());
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Table not created.");
        }
```

I put the code in Main function and run it. There is no error and the database can be opened. However, when I check the database, there is no table created. Can anyone help to see what is wrong here? Thank you.

Thank you everyone. This problem has been solved. When I created Test.mdf, I actually created in the Database folder in the project. When I double clicked the Test.mdf, it was linked to Server Explorer in Visual Studio. Then when I changed the property to Copy Always, the Test.mdf will be copied to bin/Debug/Database/. When I used Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), I was actually operating the one in bin/Debug/, rather than the one in the project folder. As a result, it looks like the table was not created. So now I linked the Test.mdf in bin/Debug/Database to the Server Explorer, I can see new tables are created.

Comment: Did you tried debugging your code? If yes did you get any exception? if yes what is the exception

Comment: A common error when using standalone database files is to be confused which file you are looking in. Are you looking in the one in the source project? or are you looking at the copy in `bin/debug` / `bin/release`? or ... where are you looking? What evidence are you using to say that it didn't create the table, basically? Note that if you build and run the project again, you could have overwritten the file again...

Comment: And are you sure you have the file at this location:bin\\Debug\\Database\\Test.mdf

Comment: Hi Jenish, I debugged it. No error at all.

Comment: Also, can you confirm the file location of the database Test from the SQL server management studio. May be the table you have created in the DB which is actually placed in bin\\Debug\\Database\\Test.mdf and the actual DB you see in SSMS is referring to different location.

Comment: Hi Marc and Manoj, thank you for you comment. I checked my database path and found that I was operating the mdf in bin\Debug but in my VS, I connected to the one in the project folder. Now I think it is working. Thanks.

Comment: As @MarcGravell pointed out you are probably not opening the same database that you are connecting to. `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)` will be different depending on if you are running in Debug or Release. You probably also have an .mdf in your project that is being copied to that location. You need to open the exact same database that is being used at run time and not overwriting it when you re-execute your app.

Comment: Thanks Igor, the problem has been solved. Thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have created the DB inside your project which will not be available in SQL Server Management studio because this is local application DB. The .mdf file location is different for the DB in SSMS.